# Adding paramter to every wordpress blog post (single)?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, url-parameters

Is there a way to add a url paramter (e.g., #blog) to every single blog post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [the `post_link` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/).

> `post_link` is a filter applied to the permalink URL for a post prior to returning the processed url by the function `get_permalink()`.
>
> This filter only applies to posts with `post_type` of `post`. For that filter which applies to custom post type look `post_type_link`.

```php
add_filter( 'post_link', static function ( $link ) {
    return $link . '#blog';
} );
```